How to use the usual oblique/italic $\varDelta$ font under svmono.cls
Under svmono.cls, various Greek letters used in math mode, are not the original ones, but are redefined as follows:
% the upright forms are defined here as \var<Character>
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varGamma}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varDelta}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varTheta}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varLambda}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varXi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varSigma}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varUpsilon}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPhi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varPsi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}

On the other hand, the Greek letters without \var are defined as:
% the definition of uppercase Greek characters
% Springer likes them as italics to depict variables
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}

But, when I process the following simple MWE,
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,nosecnum,sectrefs]{svmono}
%\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
\usepackage[varvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font

\begin{document} 
Let's check various versions of Greek symbol Delta:\\
\verb+\Delta+: $\Delta$\\
\verb+\varDelta+: $\varDelta$\\
\verb+\laplace+: $\laplace$
\end{document}

the output of \Delta and \varDelta are exactly the same under svmono.cls.
 In fact, contrary to what Springer says, \Delta is not italic as you can see.
You can see the difference from the usual article.cls.

How can I use the oblique/italics version of \Delta, i.e., the original definition of \varDelta for svmono.cls?
Thanks for your help!

I don't think you're supposed to use newtx with svmono.

@egreg, according to the reference guide and instructions of svmono.cls, both newtxtext and newtxmath are required packages. If you download svmono.zip from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation, there are guideline/instruction.pdf, which describes this requirement...

Well, they added requirement for NewTX, but forgot to change the math font settings.
Never mind: add the slantedGreek options and you'll be on track again.
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,nosecnum,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,varvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Let's check various versions of Greek symbol Delta:

\verb+\Delta+: $\Delta$

\verb+\varDelta+: $\varDelta$

\verb+\laplace+: $\laplace$

\end{document}



Thanks a lot! This is a solution really. However, the role \Delta and \varDelta are swapped from the usual article.cls... Perhaps, we need to live with this swapped situation if we need to use svmono.cls.

@BVP That's what they want.

BTW, I just found out the following from newtxdoc.pdf:  uprightGreek and slantedGreek determine the form of Greek alphabet loaded—the default is uprightGreek, which loads upright uppercase and slanted lowercase Greek symbols, ... With the option slantedGreek, which you might want to use if you cared about ISO standards, all Greek symbols are slanted. No matter which is set, \Gammaup (or \upGamma) gives you upright \Gamma, etc, and \Deltait, \zetait give you italic (i.e., slanted) versions of those letters. So, we can use \Deltait for the italic version regardless of the option.
